# CakePHP nesting two select queries

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two tables in cakePHP.

```
competencies
------------
id
name

competenceRatings
-----------------
id
competence_id
user_id
rating
```

I need a way to write the following query in the cake way:

SELECT * FROM competencies WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT competence_id FROM competence_ratings WHERE employee_id = $userId)

Someone please help me!!

What i did before going to this subquery method:

I tried competencies->hasMany->competenceRatings, competenceRatings->belongsTo->competencies relations.

```
$competencies = $this->Competence->CompetenceRating->find('all',array('CompetenceRating.user_id' => $userId,'CompetenceRating.competence_id !=' => 'Competence.id'));
```

I want to be able to get the names of competencies for which a user have NOT made any ratings into competenceRatings table. i.e., I need list of names from competencies table for which there are no entries in comptenceRatings table(for given user_id).

**EDIT**

I tried table join also:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
            array(
                'table' => 'competence_ratings',
                'alias' => 'CompetenceRating',
                'type' => 'LEFT OUTER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Competence.id = CompetenceRating.competence_id'
                )
            )
        );
$options['conditions'] = array( 'CompetenceRating.employee_id' => $employee['Employee']['id'] );

$competencies = $this->Competence->find('all',$options);
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I was talking about actual code. instead of just posting the expected outcome you should also post what you coded so far. you can just edit and complete your question above.

Comment: you have again ask same question befor 2 or 3 hrs you ask "cakePHP table joining two tables issue" this question

Comment: @mark i have edited the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would probably have to use a subquery():

```
$subqueryOptions = array('fields' => array('competence_id'), 'conditions' => array('employee_id'=>$user_id));
$subquery = $this->Competence->CompetenceRating->subquery('all', $subqueryOptions);

$res = $this->Competence->CompetenceRating->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('id NOT IN '. $subquery)
));
```

the source for subquery is here:
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/Lib/MyModel.php#L405
you need to put this in your AppModel.php

BUT I think the subquery is not necessary. You can probably make a single and easy query out of it:

```
$this->Competence->CompetenceRating->find('all', array(
    'group' => 'competence_id', 
    'conditions' => array('NOT' => 'employee_id'=>$user_id)),
    'contain' => array('Competence')
));
```

dont forget to include Competence via "contain" if you have recursive set to -1.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that! I wish to do it in a single query but i cannot make it happen. How can i make it happen? Would u mind to take a look at my EDIT?

Comment: I tried your second method. This is what it does: SELECT `CompetenceRating`.`id`, `CompetenceRating`.`competence_id`, `CompetenceRating`.`user_id`, `CompetenceRating`.`rating`, `CompetenceRating`.`remarks`, `CompetenceRating`.`dated`, `CompetenceRating`.`created`, `CompetenceRating`.`modified` FROM `appraisal`.`competence_ratings` AS `CompetenceRating` WHERE NOT (`user_id` = '28') GROUP BY competence_id

Comment: I wanted Competence table fields!

Comment: as i said, dont forget to add the competence model and its field via contain

Comment: Thanks a lot mark. And thanks for introducing the subquery plugin.