# data escaping remove for specific filed in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using subquery for `id` field.

```
$db = $this->AccountRequest->getDataSource();
        $subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
            array(
                'fields'     => array('MAX(id)'),
                'table'      => $db->fullTableName($this->AccountRequest),
                'alias'      => 'MaxRecord',
                'limit'      => null,
                'offset'     => null,
                'order'      => null,
                'group'      => array("user_id")
            ),
            $this->AccountRequest
        );

        $searching_parameters = array(
            #"AccountRequest.id IN " => "(SELECT MAX( id ) FROM `account_requests` GROUP BY user_id)"
            "AccountRequest.id IN " => "(".$subQuery.")"
        );
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
            #'fields' => array('AccountRequest.*'),
            'conditions' => $searching_parameters,
            'limit' => $limit,
            'page' => $page_number,
            #'group' => array("AccountRequest.user_id"),
            'order' => array(
                'AccountRequest.id' => 'DESC'
            )
        );

        $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('AccountRequest');
```

This structure is producing a query is:

```
SELECT
    `AccountRequest`.`id`,
    `AccountRequest`.`user_id`,
    `AccountRequest`.`email`,
    `AccountRequest`.`emailchange`,
    `AccountRequest`.`email_previously_changed`,
    `AccountRequest`.`first_name`,
    `AccountRequest`.`first_namechange`,
    `AccountRequest`.`f_name_previously_changed`,
    `AccountRequest`.`last_name`,
    `AccountRequest`.`last_namechange`,
    `AccountRequest`.`l_name_previously_changed`,
    `AccountRequest`.`reason`,
    `AccountRequest`.`status`,
    `AccountRequest`.`created`,
    `AccountRequest`.`modified`
FROM
    `syonserv_meetauto`.`account_requests` AS `AccountRequest`
WHERE
    `AccountRequest`.`id` IN '(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `syonserv_meetauto`.`account_requests` AS `MaxRecord` WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY user_id)'
ORDER BY
    `AccountRequest`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 25
```

In the subquery, its add an extra single quote so it's producing an error.

So, How can I remove these single quotes from this subquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with the sub query?

The `MAX(id)` just means it will pull the id with the largest value AKA the most recent insert. The sub query is completely redundant when you can just `ORDER BY id DESC`.

using `MAX()` will return only one record, if this is what you want to achieve you can replicate by adding `LIMIT 1`

If the sub query is just an example and is meant to be from another table I would just run the query that gets the most recent id before running the main query. Getting the last inserted id in a separate query is very quick and I cant see much of a performance loss. I think it will result in cleaner code that`s easier to follow to.

**edit 1:** From the comments it sounds like all your trying to get is a particular users latest account_requests.

You dont need the sub query at all. My query below will get the most recent account record for the user id you choose.

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'fields' => array('AccountRequest.*'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'AccountRequest.user_id' => $userID // you need to set the $userID
    )
    'page' => $page_number,

    'order' => array(
        'AccountRequest.id DESC' //shows most recent first
    ),
    'limit' => 1 // set however many you want the maximum to be
);
```

The other thing you cold be meaning is to get multiple entries from multiple users and display them in order of user first and then the order of recent to old for that user. MYSQL lets you order by more than one field, in that case try:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'AccountRequest.user_id' => $userID // you need to set the $userID
    )
    'page' => $page_number,

    'order' => array(
        'AccountRequest.user_id', //order by the users first
        'AccountRequest.id DESC' //then order there requests by recent to old
    )
);
```

Comment: I want most recent result with groupby user_id.

Comment: Im still unsure what you are trying to achieve. can you give an example of the expected output? if I know what output you want I can help you better.

Comment: GROUP BY method always return the first row of table with conditions but i want last record means latest inserted result. Thats it.

Comment: GROUP BY i would use when i want to get totals of things  e.g

`SELECT user_name, COUNT(id) FROM actions GROUP BY user_id`

Which would give me the the number of actions performed for each user that exists in the table like;

`jack | 52
james |4
stacy| 99`

Comment: are you sure you want to group by user_id and not order by user_id and created date? again if you cant show me an example of what output you are expecting from the query It is hard for me to help you.

Comment: `GROUP BY` will merge all query results into a single record(result). if you are wanting to display many results from a single user_id then `GROUP BY` is incorrect and you need to look at `ORDER BY`. From what I can see so far the subquery is not needed.

Comment: A user can request for change his name/email or other info. So in admin this listing will show by GROUP BY user ID to show separate user request when I click on  detail it's shows the all request for this selected user. So I want to show on list page the users last request for change.

Comment: i don't want only one result, i want all user's list. If i set `$userId` in WHERE then i will get only one result

Comment: how many items per user do you want to get? **only** use `GROUP BY user_id` if you want to get 1 `AccountRequest` per user. If the anwser is many per user than use the very last example I offered. it will order by user first and then order by id secondly. which is what i think you are trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109292/discussion-between-jeetendra-and-jason-joslin).

Answer (score 0):

If the example data you have added into the question is irrelevant and you are only concerned about how to do nested subqueries it has already been answered here

> [CakePHP nesting two select queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810990/cakephp-nesting-two-select-queries)

However I still think based on the data in the question you can avoid using a nested query.